# Rails: How do I advanced query with has_many related table?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have two models.

```
class Revision < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :revision_approvals
end

class RevisionApproval < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :revision
end
```

Revision can have many revision_approvals.
RevisionApproval has role (string) and decision (enum - integer) fields. Role can be process_responsible or process_coordinator.
The process_coordinator role is higher than the process_responsible role.
The decision of the process_coordinator is required for revision approval. If process_coordinator has not made any decision, the revision stays pending approval status.
If the role of revision_approval is process_coordinator, according to the decision of process_coordinator, the status of the revision changes from pending approval to approved or rejected.
I want revisions which has pending approval status. How can I do this with a single query?

**TL;DR**

revision_approvals belonging to a revision should not have the process_coordinator role. This includes revisions that don't have any revision_approval.

For example:

revisions table:

| revision_id | has any revision_approval? |
| --- | --- |
| 577 | true |
| 576 | false |
| 16 | true |
| 566 | true |
| 384 | true |

revision_approvals table:

| revision_id | role | decision |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 577 | process_responsible | 0 |
| 16 | process_responsible | 1 |
| 16 | process_coordinator | 1 |
| 566 | process_responsible | 1 |
| 384 | process_coordinator | 0 |

The query should return revisions with ids of 566, 576, 577.

The following query returns the records that I want. After a while If there is no better answer, I will add this as an answer.

```
Revision.where.not(
  id: Revision.joins(:revision_approvals)
              .where(revision_approvals: { role: :process_coordinator })
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query returns the records I want.

```
Revision.where.not(
  id: Revision.joins(:revision_approvals)
              .where(revision_approvals: { role: :process_coordinator })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all revisions:

```
Revision.all
```

If you want revisions with role revision_approval that has role "process_responsible":

```
Revision.joins(:revision_approvals).where(role: "process_responsible")
```

or

```
Revision.joins(:revision_approvals).where("revision_approvals.role = ?",  "process_responsible")
```

If you want revisions with role revision_approval that has role "process_responsible" and process_responsible 0:

```
Revision.joins(:revision_approvals).where("revision_approvals.role = ? AND revision_approvals.decision = ?",  "process_responsible", 0)
```

Revision with no revision_approval:

```
Revision.includes(:revision_approval).where(revision_approvals: { id: nil })
```

Comment: What is the result that you want?

Answer (score 0):

This returns all revisions where the revisions_approval is NOT process_coordinator

```
Revision.joins(:revision_approvals).where("revision_approvals.role != ?",  "process_coordinator")
```

Comment: This query will return revision with id number 16. But it should not return. I don't want to revisions which has any revision_approval with the process_coordinator role. None of a revision's revision_approvals should not have the process_coordinator role.